# Problems with runfile using hta html

Tags: html, windows, hta

I have this hta script and when i run it i get an error saying "RunFile1 is not defined"can any one help me fix this. Thanks.

My code:

```
<body background = "Image.png">
<TITLE>Test GUI</TITLE>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile2() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/cmd.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile3() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/regedit.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile4() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("H:\MY GUI 2.hta", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
<input type="button" value="Option 1 (notepad.exe)" name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile()"><p>
<input type="button" value="Option 2 (cmd.exe)" name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile2()"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 3 (regedit.exe)" name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile3()"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 4"(hta-file.hta)" name="run_button"  onClick="RunFile4()"><p>
<input type="button" value="Option 5" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 6" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 7" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 8" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 9" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
<input type="button" value="Option 10" name="run_button"  onClick="TestSub"><p> 
</body>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please don't use the "run" tag, as it [has been deprecated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252760/burninate-the-run-tag?cb=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've functions `RunFile(), RunFile2(), ... RunFile4()`, but not `RunFile1()`. You'll get also an error from `RunFile4()`, you need to escape backslashes and wrap a space(s)-containing string into double quotes, i.e. the first argument in `Run()` should be `'"H:\\MY GUI 2.hta"'`.